# Web application running hashcat or john the ripper

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, hashcat

Is it possible to run locally Hashcat or John the Ripper with Rails? I have to create cryptoanalysis application with web interface for studies project. What would be the best approach to do this. Heard something about communicating with local running aps with javascript...

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This gem could help you: https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_hashcat

If you run Rails you should be able to run Hashcat with it.

Comment: Thank you, Ill try it